# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat

Tags: php, imagick

I'm unable to make imagick works with local xampp.

## Error

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat`

## Code

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution(300, 300);
$im->readimage($base_dir . 'files/PDF/test.pdf');
$im->setIteratorIndex($i);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$newimgname = time();
$im->resizeImage(500, 500, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$im->cropImage(100, 100, 0, 0);
$thumbnail = $im->getImageBlob();
```

Comment: Poss duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547819/imagick-not-loading-images-with-nodecodedelegateforthisimageformat-error-mess)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please give a brief description of what you are trying to do, what you have tried to fix this issue and what your are expecting the output to be.

Comment: Wow, tough crowd today. @JeremyMiller It's not a duplicate, this is to do with PDFs. @ James Massey The question is brief, but it actually is complete.

Comment: @Danack It is quite related, but your answer is very targeted and extremely helpful. +1

Answer (score 1):

Imagick calls the ImageMagick library to do all it's processing of images. The Image Magick library does not actually handle PDFs itself, it calls GhostScript to process them and generate a PNG or Jpeg which Image Magick then reads.

The NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat is saying that Image Magick is unable to call the delegate program that it thinks it should be delegating the decoding to i.e. GhostScript.

The solution is to install GhostScript through yum or apt, and it 'should' work.

If it still doesn't work you should check what is in the delegates file for Image Magick (http://www.imagemagick.org/source/delegates.xml) for the PDF entry and make sure that it is callable from a command prompt - i.e. to check that Image Magick will also be able to find it.

Comment: I've already installed GhostScript latest version in my windows(8.1) machine. No luck yet!

Comment: How to say to Image Magick, where to find GhostScript, if GS is installed on Windows on C:\ghostscript ?

Answer (score 0):

Even after installing GhostScript, we could not get the imagick code to work after switching from AWS to Azure, getting the Delegate error.  We ended up converting the PHP code to Image Magick command line, **using the function execInBackground to run the command** ([PHP.net Exec() Page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329))

NOTE: The command line **did not work using exec alone**.  The php script would not terminate normally.

```
//from PHP.net 
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}

//create a thumbnail from the first page of PDF
//old php code
/*
$image_magick = new imagick(); 
$image_magick->setbackgroundcolor('white');
$image_magick->readImage($file_path . "[0]");
$image_magick = $image_magick->flattenImages();
$image_magick->setResolution(300,300);
$image_magick->thumbnailImage(102, 102, true);
$image_magick->setImageFormat('jpg');
$image_magick->writeImage($thumbnail_path);
*/

//command line syntax
$cmd = "magick convert " . chr(34) . $file_path . "[0]" . chr(34) . " -background white -flatten -resample " . chr(34) . "300x300" . chr(34) . " -thumbnail " . chr(34) . "102x102" . chr(34) . " -format jpg -write " . chr(34) . $thumbnail_path . chr(34);
execInBackground($cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my Server admin:
You may want to try GraphicsMagick as an alternative to Image Magick.

[Graphics Magick Homepage](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/)