# NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to use Imagick to resize pictures, but I have a problem using it... I did a lot of search, but nothing solving my problem.

So, when I try to open a picture, I just get this error message:

NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `C:\wamp\www\antiK\app\webroot/img/galery/17.png' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555

The line I typed for the test is:

$image = new Imagick(APP.'webroot/img/galery/17.png');

I would like to know, with your help, where is my problem...

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Imagick not loading images, with 'NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat' error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547819/imagick-not-loading-images-with-nodecodedelegateforthisimageformat-error-mess)

Comment: I'm giving a better view on this topic (that I already seen before)
How can I be sure that the version of Imagick I'm using is good? (I'm running PHP 5.5.12)

Comment: @Drake Try installing ImageMagick from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ and Imagick from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/imagick/

Comment: Now, I simply have "Error: Class 'Imagick' not found"...

I was used to the .exe version of ImageMagick, so I'm not sure if I did right with those files... I placed them in a folder, and then configured a systempath to them (including the 3 folders in it), I hope I did right...