# Imagick NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat using Intervention

Tags: php, laravel, imagick, intervention

Currently Imagick's `readimageblob` is called via Intervention while reading a SVG image.

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat in ..\Intervention\Image\Imagick\Decoder.php:87
```

I have seen [other stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547819/imagick-not-loading-images-with-nodecodedelegateforthisimageformat-error-mess) where this was related to an incorrect installation of Imagick but I don't think that is the case in my scenario. Those posts show that the number of supported formats of imagick is either 0 or that the format they are trying to use is not in the list of supported formats.

For me, the SVG format **is** in the list of supported formats:
[image]

Can someone tell me why I still get this exception?

Comment: How are you trying to use it; using CLI script, or in a page of some site? If it's inside a webpage, is this phpinfo generated from that server domain page directly?

Comment: It is called in one of the controllers of a website. The phpinfo is generated using the same php executable as used by the backend of the site.